# How to eliminate 'Identity added' message in terminal generated from ssh entry in .bashrc file?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, ubuntu-16.04

I set up a VPC on Amazon Web Services where I ssh into multiple Ubuntu AMI's from one bastion host AMI. I added:

```
ssh-add /home/myuser/.ssh/aws.pem
```

to my .bashrc file on my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop) so that I would not have to use 'ssh-add' every time I restart my computer.

While it is working, I get this annoying message every time I open my terminal:

```
'Identity added: /home/myuser/.ssh/aws.pem (/home/myuser/.ssh/aws.pem)'
```

How do I get rid of this message? I checked [the Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/ssh-add.1.html) under 'ssh-add' but couldn't find anything. Sorry if I've missed anything in plain sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a conditional around your .bashrc line to check if the key has already been added, and if so, skip the command.

Comment: Worked, thanks. Need to brush up on my bash scripting!